# Nested reflection

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I'm trying to set a value that's nested within another class. There are a lot of levels, which are starting to confuse me, and I need a second (or third) opinion.

The two named classes at the bottom are third party classes from Ivi.Visa.Interop.dll (a VISA communication library). I do not have access to their source code.

Visually, it looks like this:

Test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class Test : Form
    {
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // This works
        private void btn_Direct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormattedIO488 tmp = new FormattedIO488();
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();

            tmp.IO = (IMessage)rm.Open("VISA ADDRESS HERE");
            tmp.IO.TerminationCharacterEnabled = true;
            tmp.WriteString("*IDN?");

            Console.Write(tmp.ReadString().Trim());

        }

        // This does not work
        private void btn_Nested_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            A tmp = new A();

            Console.Write(tmp.SimpleTest());
        }
    }
}
```

Parent Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;

namespace Testing
{
    class A
    {

        public B tmp;
        ResourceManager rm;

        public string SimpleTest()
        {
            tmp = new B();

            tmp.session = new FormattedIO488();
            rm = new ResourceManager();

            tmp.session.IO = (IMessage)rm.Open("VISA ADDRESS HERE");

            // Reflection attempt, but does not find the property.
            foreach (var prop in tmp.session.IO.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(tmp.session.IO, null));
            }

            tmp.session.IO.TerminationCharacterEnabled = true;
            tmp.session.WriteString("*IDN?");

            return (tmp.session.ReadString().Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Testing
{
    class B : A
    {

        public dynamic session;

    }
}
```

FormattedIO488: IFormattedIO488

```
...
IMessage IO { get; set; }
...
```

IMessage: IBaseMessage

```
...
    [DispId(1610743814)]
    bool TerminationCharacterEnabled { get; set; }
...
```

**The problem:** I want to set TerminationCharacterEnabled, but during Runtime, the system can't find the property. It can find FormattedIO488.IO, but it can't find any sub-properties.

Is my reflection correct? What other options do I have when it comes to accessing properties in a class within a class?

Alternatively, is there a good example of Reflection for cases like this?

Comment: You need to show the code that you're currently using and explain *specifically* what about it isn't working.

Comment: Yes, you've said that.  You've also said that your code isn't working *and yet you haven't shown that non-working code*.  You need to provide an example program that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: You claim to be having problems getting a value through reflection and then have shown no reflection code attempting to get a value.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct you can not instantiate an interface such as IMessage, per .NET naming conventions IMessage would be an interface not an abstract class; not that it makes much difference as both can not be instantiated as they do not have implementations for anything or everything as is the case of an abstract class.  You would need to declare a class that implements the interface.

```
public class MyMessage : IMessage
{
   // ... everything that IMessage declares you implement. 
}
```

Then you could instantiate the object using your class.

You may be able to get away with not creating a duplicate class:

1. if you can find am object that implements IMessage. If  you are using reflection on an existing object and making a copy of the object, which it sounds like it might be the case, then you could find that object's type and see if it has a public constructor.
2. Use a mocking library and mock the interface... if IMessage is from an external dll and is subject to change during subsequent updates then mocking would be a suitable solution otherwise I would stay away from using mocking in live code and stick to only mocking out objects for testing purposes.

Either way - Good Luck!